# Testes de integração em cenários complexos API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Boa tarde,

Para um cenários simples eu apago todos os registros das tabelas do banco antes de executar cada teste de integração.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte como preparar o banco de dados de teste para ambientes complexos, exemplo para realizar a emissão de uma apólice de seguro são necessárias muitas tabelas preenchidas no banco de dados.

Neste caso eu teria que ter uma cópia do banco de dados de  produção  (d-1) para rodar os testes de integração ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu programo em Java.
Para fazemos teste integrados, nos preocupamos em criar a massa no próprio teste e apagar a massa no fim do teste.
Para isso criamos um utilitário de persistência, onde solicito a ele uma entidade, por exemplo "Pessoa.class" e ele me devolve um objeto do tipo Pessoa, já persistido no banco de dados. Além disso, este utilitário mantem uma lista de objetos criados durante o teste, para que no after test, eu possa excluir esses objetos. Tudo isso acontece de forma transparente.

O utilitário tem um método "criarEPersistir(Class pClasseTO)" e um "limpaObjetosCriadosNoTeste()".

Assim, a infra do teste fica bem simplificada, e o teste fica muito mais limpo.

Na minha opnião, usar cópia da base de produção, não é um bom negócio, já você não terá controle da massa de dados, além disso, tem muito mais informação do que você precisaria.

Comment: Entendi, posso criar arquivos excel que contenham as informações necessárias para rodar os testes ?

Comment: Pode ser também, isso aí é chamado de testTable, inclusive tá para usar aquivos .txt para isso. Basta as colunas estarem separadas por | ou ;. Se tiver interesse dá uma olhada neste meu post: https://edermfl.wordpress.com/2015/12/17/testando-funcionalidades-com-testtable/